How to order table based on total for elements in one column, but the elements are not unique
@Thorsten Kettner mentioned I didn't say what the problem is, so I wanted to add that. Right now the result is ordered by countries alphabetically, but I need it to be ordered by value of "ALL" for each country.
I've been playing with BigQuery public data sets, i.e. bigquery-public-data.geo_international_ports.world_port_index.
I'm selecting 'country' and 'harbor_size' columns and I'm calculating total count of country. I'm adding this as new row with value 'ALL' in column 'harbor_size'. I want to sort on this total count but in a way, where all country elements stay together. Original 'harbor_size' elements: ['S', 'M', 'L', 'V'].
Here's what I have so far: enter image description here
Query:
WITH
  total_n AS 
  (   
    SELECT     
      country,     
      "ALL" AS harbor_size,     
      COUNT(country) as hb_count   
    FROM bigquery-public-data.geo_international_ports.world_port_index
    GROUP BY country 
    ORDER BY country ASC, hb_count DESC
  )
SELECT * FROM total_n 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  country, 
  harbor_size, 
  COUNT(country) as hb_count 
FROM bigquery-public-data.geo_international_ports.world_port_index
GROUP BY country, harbor_size 
ORDER BY country ASC, hb_count DESC;

So in the end, I'd like to have something like this:



country
h_size
count
remark




US
ALL
10,000
<- sort on this


US
L
7,000



US
M
2,000



US
S
1,000



CA
ALL
9,000
<- sort on this


CA
L
6,000



CA
M
2,000



CA
S
1,000



...
...
...
...



I was considering having temp table with only 'ALL' in 'harbor_size' then adding index after sorting, so that each country would have an index, then unioning this with the other table (country, harbor_size w/ all elements, count) and sorting on the index.

You forgot to tell us what the problem with your query is. The ORDER BY in the subquery is superfluous and can be ignored by the DBMS. Subquery results are unordered data sets by definition. But the `ORDER BY clause you have at the end of the query should do the job already ecept for countries with oly one harbour size, where you got that row and the 'ALL' row in arbitrary order. Is this your problem?

Your query sorts the countries alphabetically and even has the problem that countries having only one harbour size get their 'ALL' row and size row in arbitrary order, as they have the same count.
Instead you want to order the countries by the total harbour count descending and then by country and 'ALL' followed by the country's harbor sizes.
The ORDER BY clause in your CTE is superfluous by the way, because subquery results are unordered data sets. The DBMS is free to ignore this clause altogether.
You can get the total with GROUPING SETS, as you want to group by country and horbour size and also by country. This makes the query simpler. To get the countries ordered by their total count, use a window function (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country)).
SELECT     
  country,
  COALESCE(harbor_size, 'ALL') AS hb_size,     
  COUNT(*) as hb_count   
FROM bigquery-public-data.geo_international_ports.world_port_index
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (country, harbor_size), (country) )
ORDER BY
  SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country) DESC, -- countries with many harbours first
  country ASC, -- get countries with the same harbour count in alphabetical order
  hb_count DESC, -- within each country get the harbour sizes ordered by their count
  hb_size ASC; -- and get 'ALL' before the harbour size row, for countries with just one size


Thanks for suggestion. I can't get it to work though...
On: "COALESCE(harbor_size, 'ALL') AS hb_size" I'm getting this error: "SELECT list expression references column harbor_size which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [16:12]"

Oh, I am sorry. It is true, we must group by country and harbour size, and won't use ROLLUP then, but GROUPING SETS instead. I've corrected my answer.

You have updated your answer. You want the countries listed by total harbour count. I have adjusted the query accordingly and updated my answer once more.

Awesome! Thank you so much! That works now. Just one last thing I need to account for is NULLs, because rn for "JP" it shows two "ALL" rows where first sums not null harbor_size values and the other "ALL" has count of 1 and I checked there's 1 null harbor_size row for JP

Well, why is harbor_size nullable in the first place? You may want to correct this in the table, adjust the harbour size of the row in question to S, M or L or delete it from the table. Or, if you want to exclude it from the query, use WHERE harbor_size IS NOT NULL, or if you want to default nulls to a particular harbour size in the query, have a CTE that replaces NULL with that value.

I think we should use case when, here is the query, I hope it will work.
Select
country,
case when harbor_size is null then 'ALL' 
else harbor_size 
end as harbor_size,
count(*) AS hb_count
fromm bigquery-public-data.geo_international_ports.world_port_index
group by country, harbor_size
order by
  country,
  case when harbor_size is null then 0
       when harbor_size = 'V' then 1
       when harbor_size = 'L' then 2
      when harbor_size = 'M' then 3
      when harbor_size = 'S' then 4
       else 5
  END;

